# take so long vs taking so long

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, politeness, formal-language

I've worked in a market. Suddenly they stopped my work for verification purpose. They requested me to provide a student ID card. I've sent a scanned copy of my Student ID card for verification. One week has gone still now they have not sent any confirmation email. How do I politely and without any grammatical error ask them about my verification delay?

If I want to say something like this, is it correct?

> Hi Admin, Why are you pending my Student ID verification? Why do you
>   taking so long to verify my ID?

Here which sentence is appropriate in this perspective.

*Why do you take so long to verify my ID?

Why do you taking so long to verify my ID?

Why does it take so long to verify my ID?*

You can suggest some additional formal and polite sentence. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest an alternative sentence:

> Would you please confirm if you have received and validated my Students ID that I sent last week. I am unable to work until I receive your confirmation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you take so long to verify my ID?    (1)
>   Why do you taking so long to verify my ID?  (2)
>   Why does it take so long to verify my ID?   (3)

(2) is grammatically incorrect, (1) is technically correct, but doesn't make much sense, and (3) is also correct, but would be used, for example, to ask about the process rather than the specific case where the guy is taking too long to do it.

A better question would be *Why are you taking so long to verify my ID?*, but this sounds a bit straightforward or even rude, depending on who reads it. More polite alternatives are as follow:

> I was wondering why it is taking more than usual to verify my ID.
>   Could you explain to me why it is taking more than usual to verify my ID?

Nevertheless, you should bear in mind that the correct structure for this is [**present continuous**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-continuous).

Comment: Is it ok, If I say '' Please could you let me know what might be causing the delay in verifying my Student ID? ''

Comment: Even better than the phrases I suggested, yes.

Comment: Is there any grammatical error in this sentence. " Please could you let me know what might be causing the delay in verifying my Student ID? ''

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @Rashedul Alam If you are in the UK don't use "why it is taking more than usual" use "why it is taking longer than usual" Also the Hi Admin part would freak me out. In this case i suggest a bit more formal this is not a text to the brothers

Comment: Thank you @Brad

Comment: The sentence "Could you explain me why it is taking more than usual to verify my ID?" is incorrect. It should have been "Could you explain TO me why it is taking longer than usual to verify my ID?"